# Rollover tooltips on 'List Items' on SharePoint 2013

Tags: list, jquery, rollup-image

**Front-end page:** I have a 'List' web part on my homepage, displaying IDs:

[image]

**My Database:** The web part above is displaying data from a 'List' page I have created:
[image]

**What I want to achieve:**
How do I create a rollover on the web part items to display the 'Library' name - 'Test 1234'? i.e.

[image]

**After trying Deepmala's code**

[image]

1. After replacing 'Library' with 'Description'. It's showing unidentified.
2. URL Link is missing as well, the original rollover effect is missing as well.

Comment: you can use client side rendering to achieve this. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Comment: Any jquery help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSLink to achieve the same. Below code will display Library name in tool tip:

```
window.COB = window.COB || {};
window.COB.accordionItem = {
customItemHtml: function (ctx) {

    var accordionItemHtml = "<div title='" + ctx.CurrentItem.Library + "'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
    accordionItemHtml += "</div>";  
    return accordionItemHtml;
}
};
(function () {
var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};
overrideCtx.Templates.Item = window.COB.accordionItem.customItemHtml;
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
```

Comment: Hi Deepmala, I have tried your code. However, when i replace the 'Library' field with 'Description' it's showing 'unidentified'. My original URL rollover effect went missing as well... Any help? I have updated the question with the latest development screens.

Comment: I have shared the demo html. generate the html as per your need. Regarding the undefined, make sure Desc field contains value and field with same name exists.
Also, Make sure fields added in code exists in selected view as well.